# EXPO React Native App Won't Load From Windows

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

**Hi all,**

I am starting a project with one of my team members. Our goal is to create a `React Native` app with `Expo`. This isn't the first time I've used `Expo` or `React Native`.

**The problem:**
I use `Ubuntu 18.04` and my friend uses `Windows 10`. As usual `Windows` is screwing something up. When my friend runs `expo start` in the same project as me he won't be able to connect to the project from his phone, not am I. But when I start the `Expo` project with `expo start` everything works just fine for both him and me.

After testing everything we came to the conclusion that it is not his/my phone or internet. It is his machine that is blocking something and we don't know how to resolve it.

1. We've tried old projects that run fine on my machine with both phones.
2. We've tried multiple devices and internet connections.
3. We've tried turning of all firewalls on his machine.

I posted the original help request on [Expo Forums](https://forums.expo.io/t/new-app-doesnt-load-on-hotspot/13339).

**I hope someone is able to help!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. It seems to be `VMware`/`Virtualbox`.

Here is a quoted solution which I found [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/438).

> Solution for windows 10. 
>   Go to cmd and write ipconfig. Look what is
>   the first Ethernet adapter. It should be Ethernet adapter Ethernet. If
>   it is not and it is something like Ethernet adapter Virtualbox... Then
>   this is the problem voalaa. Expo is taking the ip adress of the
>   virtualbox. So go to "Network connections" right click on the adapter
>   you want disable and change the status to disable. Connect you
>   computer to ethernet and you phone to the same wifi network. Restart
>   Expo, then the default url should be changed. Select host->lan, start
>   the app and then -> run on android. That's it.

I hope that this will help other people!